# ShellExecute, spaces in path

Tags: windows, vb6

I need to execute a external program from my VB6 code using ShellExecute: the problem I face is that when the path string has any space it doesn't work:

```
Dim Path As String
Path = "E:\PROYECTOS WG\Gama EVO 2\WontaGes\facturae\facturae.jar"
ShellExecute Me.hWnd, "open", "javaw.exe ", "-jar '" & Path & "'", "", 0
```

When I run it, it throws and error like "Unable to access jar file "E:\PROYECTOS"

But in CMD (command line) I can run it

```
 javaw -jar "E:\PROYECTOS WG\Gama EVO 2\WontaGes\facturae\facturae.jar"
```

How can this be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
Dim Path As String
Path = Chr$(34) & "E:\PROYECTOS WG\Gama EVO 2\WontaGes\facturae\facturae.jar" & Chr$(34)
ShellExecute Me.hWnd, "open", "javaw.exe ", "-jar " & Path, "", 0
```

The `Chr$(34)` inserts a double quote instead of a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes round the path name:

```
Path = ""E:\PROYECTOS WG\Gama EVO 2\WontaGes\facturae\facturae.jar""
```

and delete the single quotes in the ShellExecute line:

```
ShellExecute Me.hWnd, "open", "javaw.exe ", "-jar " & Path & , "", 0
```

Comment: You need three quotes not two. Odd number of quotes at beginning or end of string, and even number of quotes in a string. *Two quotes = one quote*. So `x = "cat"` has the word cat without quotes in `x`. `x = """Cat"""` has "cat" in `x`. First quote starts a string, second two quotes are one quote in the string.