# cmd.exe does not recognize command given with ShellExecute from Delphi

Tags: delphi, cmd

This is the code to execute the command :

```pascal
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', PWideChar('/c '+cmd+' & pause'), nil, SW_SHOW);
```

With this content for cmd (the quotes are present in the string) :

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=root --password=root --port=3306 --host=localhost --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --hex-blob db > "C:/backup/db.sql"
```

Outputs the error :

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Running the exact same command from a manually opened instance of cmd.exe works, so this is a problem with ShellExecute but I don't know what I can do to debug this.

Edit : I tried replacing the backslashes with forward slashes in case this was the problem, but it wasn't.

Comment: The Windows library function to call for running an application is [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) without or with a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) should not be used on executable to run is known with its full path like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe`.

Comment: It would be better to look on tutorials about usage of `CreateProcess` with Delphi like [this one](https://riptutorial.com/delphi/example/18340/createprocess) or looking on questions and answers found on Stack Overflow with [[delphi\] CreateProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+CreateProcess). The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` calls also `CreateProcess` to run an executable like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe`. The output of the executed program to `stdout` (standard output) can be captured directly by Delphi coded program.

Comment: PS: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. There are explained the criteria applied by `cmd.exe` on the argument string(s) after option `/C` or `/K`. They are not trivial to understand on program to run specified first must be enclosed in `"` because of containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` and additionally redirection operators like `>`, `>>`, `|` or command operators like `&`, `&&`, `||`. It might work to enclose the entire command line in `"` and use before option `/c` also the options `/d` and `/s`.

Comment: BTW: Does `mysqldump.exe` not have an option to write the output directly into a text file like `C:\backup\db.sql`? The documentation page [4.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) describes the option `--result-file`. The directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as described by Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: So what I ended up doing was putting the command in a temp .bat file, and telling cmd to run that then delete it. Works like a charm and since it's for internal tools management I'm not going to look further. Thanks for the suggestions anyway :)

Comment: Take a look at this post: [ShellExecute, spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59487468/16184113)

Answer (score -1):

I've never done this. I always use the Raize / Konopka Launch component. It's part of the library found in GetIt. In fact, I just used it the other day to run a shell that ran a bat file the program generated that contained a curl statement. I put a 'pause' at the end to allow me to examine it before it closed.

You could also read through the code and see what it's doing if you want to DIY.

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works through links. Please put a link instead of letting each reader research it on their own where it can be found. Also this is no solution, but rather an alternative/workaround, not even unveilling why it should work better than what the comments already suggested.

Comment: @AmigoJack First of all, you should familiarize yourself with the Terms of Service here. Links to stuff like this are prohibited. That said, if you have a version of Delphi released in the past few years, then you know it has this library called GetIt built right into the IDE. You click a link in the IDE and the GetIt Dashboard opens. Then you type "konopka" into the search bar and it shows the library. Then you click "Install". Three or four clicks, all links, just what the internet was designed to do, as you say.

Comment: "_stuff like this_" is too vague and can't be violating the TOS. The Q is not bound to any Delphi particular version, and clicking in an IDE is still only a relative description. Not linking to any documentation or checking the source yourself if it is related to `ShellExecute()` or `CreateProcess()` and not putting your story into actual code can't be reasoned with license issues only. Your A should have been a comment.

Comment: @AmigoJack you are totally free to do whatever you like to further the conversation, but complaining about my response is only making you look bad. The Konopka tools are FREE, they are EASILY AVAILABLE within the Delphi IDE, there's NO external link for them, they belong to Embarcadero who chooses how to distribute them (wihin GetIt) and anybody with a version of Delphi that has GeteIt support built-in will have no problem accessing them. You are more than welcome to do whatever you want to make it easier instead of complaining, but I don't know what that would look like. FIni.